# How to get gitlab tag of deployed service?

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm building a spring boot service. Everyone of my releases gets tagged with a specific version number

[image: my tagged releases]

Now I can chose one of these releases to deploy them.
But is there a way to ask the deployed service for his version number? I would like to be able to send e.g. an API request to my deployed service (GET service/version) and receive the tagname (e.g. v2.0.0) as response.

One idea was to trigger a new pipeline for each new tagged version, there I have to rebuild the service and add the tagname into a file in the root directory of my service. Then I can build an API to send the file to me when requested. Is there maybe an easier way that I'm overlooking?

Comment: How are you deploying the service? Are you deploying via AutoDevOps, or a different method? Generally you're on the right path, where if you want to ask the service for what version it's deployed with, you'll have to set the version either at build or at deploy time.

Comment: I'm depoying it at AWS using Cloud Foundry... how can you set it at deploy time? That would be my prefered way so that I don't have to re-build anything.

Comment: Ok I found out now, thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm glad you found it! Can you post the solution of where you found it for folks who may stumble onto this thread in the future? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

1. Tell Spring Boot to look for a variable e.g. RELEASE_VERSION
   -> Spring will not find it within it's code and automatically look for it in the deployment environment
   -> In my case I had a `manifest-my-company.yml` file where I created a environment variable
   `RELEASE_VERSION: '((RELEASE_VERSION))'`. But I'm not sure if that's specific to
   my company.
2. Create an API that returns the value of this variable:

   ```
   @RestController
   public class GetVersionController implements GetVersionApi {

     @Value("${RELEASE_VERSION:no version number available}") //"no version number available" is the dafault value
     private String releaseVersion;

     @Override
     public String getVersion() throws IOException {
       return releaseVersion;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Now pass the commit tag value as that variable in when deploying your service. In my case I used a company script for deployment to Cloud Foundry and could simply add the variable in my `gitlab-ci.yml` specification:

   ```
   deploy to prod:deploy to prod:
     extends: .deploy_to_prod
     script:
     - deploy_to_cf.sh RELEASE_VERSION=${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
     ...
   ```